Connecting an op-amp to a second-stage amplifier: loading effect considerations
I designed an amplifier with an OPA838 as follows:

First scenario: I want to connect the OPA838 to a next stage voltage LNA (Low Noise Amplifier).
What components or circuit should I add to my output circuit to secure the stability of the OPA and assure that the OPA will not be affected by the next stage, and also not affect the LNA circuit?
The input impedance of the LNA is 115 Ω (the input impedance of the LNA is adjustable and the minimum is 115 Ω).
Second scenario: I want to measure the output of the OPA with a normal oscilloscope (10x probe). Should I connect an SMA connector to the output pin of the OPA directly, or is some extra component needed as well?
In general, what is the best practice to securely isolate two amplifiers from each other to make sure neither affects the other one?
Next stages amplifiers:


What is the input source? The OPA838 is not unity gain stable.

@ Kevin White dear Kevin, the input source is a transducer with 1nF capacitance, which can make the circuit stable.

A common way to drive a coax connector is with a 49.9 (standard value) series resistor.
This performs multiple functions:

It isolates the load from the amplifier which minimizes the possibility of causing instability.

It provides a series termination for any cable that is connected. This will absorb reflections and provide a clean transient response. You will need to account for the resistor in any gain measurements as there will be a 50% reduction in signal when driving a 50 ohm load. (or corresponding reduction for other impedances).

It provides some protection against short-circuits to ground.


For driving high impedance loads with low frequencies (such as directly into a scope) 50 ohms is low enough to  ignore.
In addition to the resistor at the output you may need to incorporate other measures (or choose a different opamp) as the OPA838 is decompensated and is not unity gain stable. As shown it will probably be unstable with nothing connected to its input.

dear Kevin, thank you very  much for your nice answer, would you please let me know your idea about connecting the output to a next stage voltage LNA (Low Noise Amplifier) , the input impedance of the next stage is 115 Ohm, should I consider more components, or just the 50 Ohm isolation resistor is enough?

@Andromeda - if the second stage is directly connected without a cable or significant capacitance then you can connect it directly. If it is connected via a cable then a 50 ohm resistor should be adequate.

the connection will be through a cable to the  second stage?  the cable is relatively long ~60 CM. Then I will consider the 50 ohm resistor.

@Andromeda - if you are doing this on a PCB then I usually put the resistor in. The cost of a small surface mount resistor is negligible. If it is not needed you can put in a zero ohm resistor, you can also use 50 ohm or any other value if you wish. Such a resistor is also useful at debug time as you can remove it temporarily to disconnect the amplifier from the next stage.

@ Kevin White dear Kevin, I add the actual next stages amplifiers to this post, to be more clear what I was talking about, would you please let me know, if still 50 Ohm resistor is enough to be place in the output of OPA838? please also consider there will be 70 CM cable form OPA838 output to the LNA input.

@Andromeda - Yes - the 50 ohm resistor is to match the cable to avoid reflections. It acts a a series termination. Although there will be reflections from the LNA since it has a higher input impedance than the cable impedance those reflections when they are reflected back to the resistor at the output of the OPA838.

thanks Kevin, is there any solution that we can solve the reflection of the LNA as well? to make sure everything will work without problem.

@Andromeda - not necessary - many systems operate with only source termination. You could add a parallel resistor at the LNA end to match the cable impedance, but not necessary.
